# What is the difference between a guajillo and a cayenne pepper?

Tags: chili-peppers

They look the same to me but I can't find literature on how they are different.

Answer (score 2):

The Guajillo is a dried Mirasol chili. The Mirasol is in the same family as the Cayenne (Capsicum annuum),  but with 2,500-5,000 Scovilles compared to Cayenne's 30,000 - 50,000 Scovilles, it has significantly less heat.

Comment: Do you know if how different they are for medicinal purposes? There is a remedy that calls for cayenne and I have a guajillo plant outside.

Comment: I followed your lead on scovilles and found that capsaicin is what makes a pepper healthy but its also what makes it spicy so I guess that answers the question

Comment: I don't know of any medicinal properties of either, but if it stems from capsaicin, greater scovilles = more capsaicin. To accept this as the answer to your question, you can click the green checkmark.

Comment: I don't feel like creating a new answer but you should note that even though they are in the same family, the two peppers are not similar at all. Guajillos are sweet and larger and used to make rich pepper sauces. Cayennes are used only to make things spicy. They are too small and way too spicy to be used for pepper flavor or as bulk in a sauce.